# Solving 2 windows synchronization

Tags: java, swing, synchronization, jframe

I'd like to use button. It will call jFrame in which I want to collect data about new user, after accepting info window is closed.
Now I'd like to save collection of user to file. Problem is that: both event (new window and serialization) occur at the same time, so if I had 3 users in collection and use this button, then those three will be saved. Fourth one will be saved if I push it once again to create 5th user...
I assume it is due to existance of 2 threads: how can I make saving thread wait till new window is closed?

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            NewUserGUI dodana = new NewUserGUI ();
            dodana.setVisible(true);

            User tempUser= new User();

            tempUser= dodana.getUser();

            listOfUsers.add(tempUser);

        }
    });


     {

    try {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("users.obiekt"));
        out.writeObject(listOfUsers);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();


    }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're already on EDT there is no much sense to invoke this code using EventQueue.invokeLater(...). Doing that you're scheduling user addition to the event queue, so it's likely to be invoked way after list is persisted. Next, you probably want to wait until your frame is closed to get a data for new user. So, use an appropriate listener for that:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    final JFrame dodana = new NewUserGUI();
    dodana.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            User tempUser = dodana.getUser();
            listOfUsers.add(tempUser);
            try {
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("users.obiekt"));
                out.writeObject(listOfUsers);
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException i) {
                i.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    dodana.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Hmm seems it doesn't work... It never calls methid windowClosing

Comment: It works in my tests. Could you please share NewUserGUI source code?

Comment: It is standard jFrame with few textFields and one button:
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        String nazwa = zNazwa.getText();
        int wiek = Integer.parseInt(zWiek.getText());
        int waga = Integer.parseInt(zWaga.getText());
        double wzrost = Double.parseDouble(zWzrost.getText()) / 100;
        
        tempUser.ustawDaneUzytkownika(wzrost,wiek, waga, nazwa);
       
        setVisible(false);
        
    }

Comment: Looks like you're not closing the frame, but only hiding it. No problem with that, we just need to use different adapter method. Please try updated code from the answer.